# Why operator cannot be in parentheses?

Tags: c++, c

The question comes when I tried to make a macro like this:

```
#define OP1(a,b,op) (a) op (b)
```

then I was wondering why not also put op into parentheses, as it is also a macro parameter.

I then find I cannot even have this:

```
1 (+) 1;
```

otherwise there will be error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
```

Can anyone tell me where is the rule saying operator cannot be in parentheses? I really cannot find it. Thank you.

Comment: It will be buried in the language *grammar* somewhere. C and C++ will differ in this respect; the former will, I'm sure, be easier to spot.

Comment: There is `std::plus` and the like which would work for your case as a workaround, by the way.

Comment: Please please don't make macros like this

Comment: Why, can't, I, put, a, comma, after, every, word, in, a, sentence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**§ 7.6.6** (expr.add) defines "additive expressions" as:

```
additive-expression:
    multiplicative-expression
    additive-expression + multiplicative-expression
    additive-expression - multiplicative-expression
```

No parens around the operator allowed.

Answer (score 1):

There actually isn't any rule that says an operator should not be in parenthesis. But there is a rule that states that, "for a binary operator like `+`, the value on either sides of the operator must be valid operands like 5, 5.2".

So the expression `(+)` to the compiler means you are adding two parentheses (left paren, plus, right paren) together which is not supported by the language.

Putting macro parameters in parenthesis is good practice of course, but there is actually no need for putting the operator in this case inside parenthesis as there is no way of passing a complicated operator expression so you can rest assured that your macro will always work.

Answer (score 1):

In programming, as in mathematics, the parentheses are used to override the operators precedence.

Without parentheses, `2 + 3 * 4` is evaluated as `2 + (3 * 4)` because the multiplication (`*`) has a higher precedence than the addition (`+`). One can use parentheses to force the addition of `2` and `3` happen before the multiplication (of the result) by `4` by placing them around the addition operator and its operands as `(2 + 3) * 4`.

Both `3 * 4` and `2 + 3` in the expressions above are valid expressions.

`+` in the expression `1 (+) 2` is not a valid expression. More, assuming the parentheses contain a valid sub-expression, the entire expression is invalid because it is just a list of values without operators to connect them into an expression.

Even more, this is also **not** the way you learned in school to write mathematical expressions.

---

Back to your `#define`, to avoid hidden errors and headache (due to the operators precedence) you should always enclose the expanded value of such a macro into parentheses like this:

```
#define OP1(a,b,op) ((a) op (b))
```